# Get content of div box from another page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to retrieve the content of a particular div box from another page, and some googling suggested jquery may be able to do this, but I'm struggling to get it to work. I've never used jquery before.

The content I'm trying to retrieve is located on `webpage.com/test.html` and the div ID is "page-content".

The page I wish to display this on is located at `webpage.com/folder1/folder2/page.html`, and the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"></div>

<script>
$("#div1").load("test.html #page-content");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I get this to work? Is there an alternative method that would be better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax code to solve this problem:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
       url:test.html,
       type:'GET',
       success: function(data){
           $('#div1').html($(data).find('#page-content').html());
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify how I should implement that? It's not clear how that translates over with the div names or webpage addresses I've used.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. Could you please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- use localstorage. This will allow you to store data across pages. Calculate the data in test.html, load it in the localstorage and then fetch it on the other page.

  localStorage.setItem("name", "john"); -> insert the data

  localStorage.getItem("lastname"); -> use the inserted data later
- Use jQuery's load method like so

  $("#div1").load("test.html #page-content");

In general, jQuery allows you to access elements and data on the same page. It is meant to allow you to work with elements on the same page after they have loaded. If the data in your element - test.html #page-content is dynamically added it will be available only after test.html was loaded. This is why jQuery is not meant to be used to get content from another page.

Answer (score 0):

According to your files info and example code, I think the problem is the `test.html` path, try this:

```
<script>
$("#div1").load("../../test.html #page-content");
</script>
```

or

```
$("#div1").load("/test.html #page-content");
```